# Make images transform in turn on hover

Tags: css

I have a bunch of social media buttons and I gave them a small transform and scale effect. The problem is that they all transform at the same time when hovered over.

How can I make this transform effec activate on each individual button when hovered on instead of all of them at once?

This is my HTML:

```
   <div id="social">

     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ionut.andrei.92" target="_blank"><img src="img/icons/facebook.svg" alt="Facebook"></a>

     <a href="https://vk.com/id362685172" target="_blank"><img src="img/icons/vk.svg" alt="VKontakte"></a>

     <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ioan_andrei93/" target="_blank"><img src="img/icons/instagram.svg" alt="Instagram"></a>

     <a href="https://twitter.com/IoanAndrei11" target="_blank"><img src="img/icons/twitter.svg" alt="Twitter"></a>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#social img{
width: 55px;
height: 55px;
position: relative;
left: 1100px;
top: -50px;



#social:hover img{
transform: scale(1.25);
transition: transform .25s ease;
```

Comment: simply make the hover on each one of them and not all of them ... [read the selector your wrote for hover and you will understand]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to apply your hover styles on links `a` tag instead of on `#social` directly.
If you apply them on`#social` they are applied to the whole social block, so to all images.

```css
#social a img {
display: inline-block;
transition: transform .25s ease;
}

#social a:hover img {
transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="social">

     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ionut.andrei.92" target="_blank"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="Facebook"></a>

     <a href="https://vk.com/id362685172" target="_blank"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="VKontakte"></a>

     <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ioan_andrei93/" target="_blank"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="Instagram"></a>

     <a href="https://twitter.com/IoanAndrei11" target="_blank"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="Twitter"></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Aurelien ) The code now works and look great.